# Laravel 4.2 and PHP 7.0 Error handling

Tags: php, laravel

Old Laravel and new PHP have different formats of errors, and because of that I can't properly launch my Laravel 4.2 application, because I get:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Exception\WhoopsDisplayer::display()
>   must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given

I've searched for solution but was not able to find anything. How can be this situation solved? Should I try installing `PHP 5` alongside with `PHP 7`? Or a Virtual Machine with `PHP 5`, and run my app in it? Or change something in `bootstrap/compiled.php`, where these errors get caught?

Comment: Laravel 4.1 ?? it's either 5.1 or 4.2

Comment: @GauravGupta 4.2, my bad

Comment: You can switch out which error handler your Laravel application uses, but since Laravel 4.2 is not made for php7 and will not be upgraded for PHP7, its easier for you to upgrade your application.

Comment: It could be 4.1.. obviously there was a version before 4.2.  But nothing before 5.1 supported PHP 7.  So yes, you'll need to install PHP 5, and how you do it is up to you.